# Creating a singleton with allocWithZone:

Tags: objective-c, singleton, alloc

`BNRItemStore` is a singleton, and I was confused on why `super allocWithZone:` must be called instead of plain old `super alloc`. And then override `alloc` instead of `allocWithZone`.

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"

@implementation BNRItemStore

+(BNRItemStore *)sharedStore {
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

    if (!sharedStore)
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone: nil] init];

    return sharedStore;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedStore];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[super alloc]` will call through to `allocWithZone:`, which you've overridden to do something else. In order to actually get the superclass's implementation of `allocWithZone:` (which is what you want there) rather than the overridden version, you must send `allocWithZone:` explicitly.

The `super` keyword represents the same object as `self`; it just tells the method dispatch mechanism to start looking for the corresponding method in the superclass rather than the current class.

Thus, `[super alloc]` would go up to the superclass, and get the implementation there, which looks something like:

```
+ (id) alloc
{
    return [self allocWithZone:NULL];
}
```

Here, `self` still represents your custom class, and thus, your overridden `allocWithZone:` is run, which will send your program into an infinite loop.

Comment: stumped, this is on the subtler side of an introductory ObjC course, so if you've got questions about my answer, I'm happy to try to clarify.

Comment: Thanks! I do have one question. If I deleted the method that overrides allocWithZone: would it be safe to call super alloc instead of super allocWithZone: in sharedStore?

Comment: Yes. The reason for overriding `allocWithZone:` is to restrict any users of this class from creating another instance. They would call `alloc` (or possibly `allocWithZone:` directly; instead of allocating a new instance, you instead return the existing one. This is the key part of making the class a singleton.

Comment: Ohh I see. So is the decision between calling super alloc and overriding alloc vs. calling super allocWithZone: and overriding allocWithZone: completely arbitrary?

Comment: No, because if you overrode `alloc`, a client could still (conceivably) use `allocWithZone:` to create a new instance. Since `alloc` just calls through to `allocWithZone:`, overriding the latter covers both.

Comment: Thanks this conversation really helped!

Comment: @W'rkncacnter thanks for your explanation guy but I've a further question for you: why `[super alloc]` returns an instance of our custom class? Isn't `[super alloc]` calls the `alloc` method of parent class because of the word `super`? I can't figure out why `[super alloc]` returns the instance of our custom class **instead** an instance of `NSObject` - that is, the ***super*** class. (in OP's code the interface says `@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject`, I'm reading the same book :)

Comment: @Fred: You should really post this as a separate question, because you'll get clearer and better answers than can fit in a comment, but `super` goes and looks in the superclass for the implementation of the method -- just the code. The identity of the object on which the method is called is the same as `self`. So the superclass's implementation of `alloc` does something like "get a chunk of zeroed memory the size of `self`'s class", not "get a chunk of memory the size of the class in which this method is implemented". If it did the latter, every subclass would have to provide its own `alloc`.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Okay, then the `[super method]` means to execute the `method` found in the super class **on** the current class - that is, `self`, right? I get confused with your last sentence. Why every subclass would have to provide its own `alloc`? In this hypothetical case the research for the method `alloc` shouldn't go upwards until in the class hierarchy the method was found?

Comment: @FredCollins: Please post a proper question rather than carrying this on in comments.

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone%3a):

> This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer
>   used by Objective-C.