# difference between these two implementations of thread safe initializers in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, nspredicate, synchronized

So I have a singleton and Im trying to understand the difference between these two implementations: functionally I have tried running my code with both of them and they both work

However, I notice that in the 1st implementation there is no [self alloc] being called instead the call is to [super alloc]. Im a bit perplexed by this. It seems to work but it seems a bit magical so Im wondering if someone can clarify

1st way:

```
 +(id)getSingleton
 {

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    locMgrSingleton = [[super alloc] init];

        });

     return locMgrSingleton;

 }
```

Another way

```
 +(id)getSingleton
 {
     @synchronized(self)
     {
         if (locMgrSingleton == nil)
         {
             locMgrSingleton = [[self alloc]init];
             NSLog(@"Created a new locMgrSingleton");
         }
         else
        {
            NSLog(@"locMgrSingleton exists");
         }

     }

     return locMgrSingleton;
 }
```

Comment: The first one should be using `self alloc`.

Comment: Are you asking about the differences in the synchronization mechanisms, or the difference between `[self alloc]` and `[super alloc]`? For the second, this may help: [Creating a singleton with allocWithZone:](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11962913) (assuming you've overridden `alloc`, anyways).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `[self alloc]` vs `[super alloc]` makes no difference unless the class also overrides `+alloc`. That said, it should be calling `[self alloc]`. I'll bet it's calling `super` because this was probably adapted from an implementation that override `+alloc` to return a singleton.

In any case, the difference between the two patterns, besides `self` vs `super`, is explained in my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat/9119089#9119089), but in short, `dispatch_once()` is the modern way to do this. It's faster than `@synchronized`, and carries more semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As said on e.g. http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.fi/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html, the `dispatch_once` call simply seems to be somewhat faster than `@synchronized(self)`.

As to why `[super alloc]` instead of `[self alloc]`, I don't see any reason why it would specifically apply to the `dispatch_once` version but not the other. In a static method, `self` simply refers to the class itself (and `super` to its direct superclass), and I'd see it as a shorthand for writing the actual class name, nothing more.

I've only ever used `[self alloc]` though, since I'd anyway otherwise written the name of the current class, not its superclass. No idea if specifically calling `[super alloc]` carries any special significance.

Answer (score 1):

In a class method, `self` points to the class itself. In both of your implementations, `[self alloc]`, `[MySingleton alloc]` and `[super alloc]` are all semantically equivalent—unless you for some odd reason override `+alloc`.

One reason you might want to use `[super alloc]` over others is when you explicitly mark `+alloc` unavailable in your declaration with a compiler directive:

`+(instancetype) alloc __attribute__((unavailable("alloc not available")));`

or

`+(instancetype) alloc NS_UNAVAILABLE;`

Otherwise, compiler will raise an error when you try to `+alloc` an instance of your singleton class—and that's usually what you want except for when you `+alloc` a shared singleton instance in dispatch_once.